# python stop selenium standalone server

Tags: python, selenium

How would I stop the selenium-server-standalone. I know you can start it by `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar` But how would you stop it? Also, is there a simple way to script it in python to start and stop it as I am running tests.I feel like this is pretty simple. But am unable to find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the server with `subprocess.Popen`, and shut it down with    `sel.shut_down_selenium_server()`:

```
import selenium
import socket
import subprocess
import shlex
import sys
import time

# CHANGE path='/path/to/selenium-server.jar' AS NEEDED:
def start_server(path='/path/to/selenium-server.jar'):
    null=open('/dev/null')
    proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('java -jar {p}'.format(p=path)),
                          stdout=null,stderr=null)
    return proc

def shutdown_server(sel):
    sel.shut_down_selenium_server()

def start_selenium(host="localhost",
                   port=4444,
                   browserStartCommand="*firefox",
                   browserURL="http://www.google.com/webhp"):
    sel=selenium.selenium(host,port,browserStartCommand,browserURL)
    try:
        sel.start()
    except socket.error as err:
        proc=start_server()
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            sel.start()
        except socket.error as err:
            sys.exit(err)
    return sel

if __name__=='__main__':
    sel=start_selenium()
    time.sleep(1)
    sel.stop()
    shutdown_server(sel)
```